# Why is there a ReferenceError? Vue Firestore

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

Here is my code trying to fetch the user's information from the *users* collection in Firestore.

```js
import db from "./firebaseInit";
import firebase from "firebase";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      uid: null,
      user: null
    };
  },
  created() {
    if (firebase.auth().currentUser) {
      // We're logged in
      this.uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
      console.log("The uid is: ", this.uid);
    }

    var docRef = db.collection("users").doc(this.uid);
    docRef
      .get()
      .then(doc => {
        if (doc.exists) {
          this.user = doc.data(); // This is the line with the ReferenceError
          console.log("This user is: ", user);
        } else {
          // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
          console.log("No such document!");
        }
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting document:", error);
      });
  },
  methods: {
    updateProfile() {
      var docRef = db
        .collection("users")
        .doc(this.uid)
        .update(this.user);
    }
  }
};
```

I am getting the following error in the catch block, although I have verified that the doc exists and is getting fetched. However, I seem not to be able to access my user variable defined in the data. This is the error:

Error getting document:

> ReferenceError: user is not defined

Please let me know if you have any idea what might be happening.

Comment: Actually, it's more likely to be the next line ~ `console.log("This user is: ", user)`. You probably meant to use `this.user`

Comment: You are missing `this` with `user`. Your variable is `this.user` not user.

Comment: Excellent, that was absolutely it. I feel silly; thanks Phil!!!

Comment: @JonathanPerry don't worry we all do mistakes :) just help other when they needed